# Acesso simultâneo

Tags: php, javascript, html, htaccess

Existiria alguma forma de limitar o acesso simultâneo sem utilizar o banco de dados? Existe alguma forma de fazer utilizando .htaccess?
Pois estou tentando limitar acesso a um arquivo que não vem na extensão PHP.

Comment: Eu não conheço um modo sem banco. Mas como gambiarra às vezes pode ajudar, de repente renomeando o arquivo a cada acesso.